# How to make mongoDB instance available all other modules in node.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb

In my application im using node.js with mongoDB.Below is my sample code.

```
var mongodb = require('mongodb');
var server = new mongodb.Server("localhost", 27017, {});

new mongodb.Db('test', server, {w: 1}).open(function (error, client) {
    if (error) throw error;
    var collection = new mongodb.Collection(client, 'test_collection');
    collection.insert({hello: 'world'}, {safe:true},
    function(err, objects) {
        if(!err){
            console.log('Data inserted successfully.');
        }
        if (err && err.message.indexOf('E11000 ') !== -1) {
            // this _id was already inserted in the database
        }
    });
});
```

Now i need the mongoDB instance to other modules in my app.How can i do this.

Comment: Please format your code. I did it for you this time, but it's much easier to read if it's formatted.

Comment: @tjameson ok thanks.Hereafter i will do on my own

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple way, if we assume the code you posted is in app.js you can rewrite line 2 to:

```
var server = exports.db = new mongodb.Server("localhost", 27017, {});
```

And in the modules that needs access to the instance simply write:

```
require('app').db
```

A more common way is probably to put shared stuff in a settings.js file or to have a dedicated database interface module.

**Update**

To get access to the opened client you'd in the same way expose the client:

```
new mongodb.Db('test', server, {w: 1}).open(function (error, client) {
  exports.client = client;
  // ...
});
```

Comment: i need the client object mentioned in the mongoDB open function.I don't want to repeat the open connection in every module.

Comment: Updated with an example on that. However if you want more abstraction I'd suggest you look into something like mongoose.